# Is there a way to organize applications in GNOME Shell's Applications menu?

Tags: gnome, extension

Since by default, GNOME organizes its "Applications" pane in alphabetical order, there is always a sprawling mess of applications, and I don't like how it automatically arranges them into categories ("Accessories", "Electronics", "Games", etc). Is there perhaps a shell extension so that I can manually organize my applications in folders or something? Windows-style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install alacarte, which shows up as an app called "Main Menu". You can create your own menus, drag apps (menu items) into them, then uncheck the normal menus / items, and only your custom menus will show up as the categories in the applications pane.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this only adds or removes items from the list altogether. Isn't there a way to rearrange the items?

Answer (score 0):

Open up main-menu from applications and you can move them up and down as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called Meow which, when installed, allows you to edit the Gnome menu items.  It also allows you to create and delete folders, and hide menu items you don't want to see.

It is not available in the repositories, so [click here](http://pnmougel.github.io/meow/) for the github page which includes installation instructions.